# Is there a file sharing module for BigBlueButton?

Tags: java, flash, apache-flex, adobe, tomcat6

As the question titles, I want to know if some of you guys that have worked with BigBlueButton have found or have used a file sharing module. I've seen it on some basic documentation but still nothing concrete.

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in BigBlueButton!

At the moment, there is no file sharing module in BigBlueButton.  We have a road map of our plans for additional modules, but a file sharing module isn't a priority right now.  See

http://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/wiki/RoadMap1dot0#Additional_Modules

To see how we set our priorities (and how you can influence the development or add such a module yourself) see

http://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/wiki/FAQ#When_will_feature_X_be_implemented

### Regards,... Fred

BigBlueButton Developer